# How to display array in xaml under UWP C#

Tags: c#, arrays, uwp, uwp-xaml

How to display array in xaml the way that each line is on separate row and each row is split into separate textblocks?

I split line like so:

```
string[] splitLines = line.Split(';');
itemsControl.Items.Add(line);
```

Then, in xaml I display it like so:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl"
              ItemsSource="{Binding itemsControl}"
              FontSize="24">                        
              <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <Grid Width="Auto"
                            Margin="0 12"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center">                                    
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Name="txtblk0" Text="{Binding }" />
                            </StackPanel>

                     </Grid>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This way I get each line from my .xls file in separate row, but the separator ';' is included in the returned content of row.
Now I would like to remove ';' separator and put each word from each line on separate textblock, like so:

```
for (int index = 0; index < splitLines.Length; index++)
            {

                itemsControl.Items.Add(splitLines[index]);

            }
```

This breaks each line into separate words, but unfortunately, each word is put on separate row(instead to populate 5 textblocks with each line's words.

Any idea how to show each .xls line in separate row, but then also split each line into words and put them in separate textblocks in separate columns?

**EDIT**
I have tried the solution from Alexej Sommer, I get some erors though:

```
ItemsData dataitem = new ItemsData
                {
                value0 = splitLines[0];
                value1 = splitLines[1];
                value2 = splitLines[2];
                value3 = splitLines[3];
                value4 = splitLines[4];
            }
            items.Add(dataitem);
```

In this piece of code I get first semicolon underscored and error says:

> } expected.

Then, values 1 - 4 are underscored and error says:

> The name (X) does not exist in the current content

At last, dataitem gets underscored and same error shows up.

**EDIT 2 --**

I managed to fix the problem. There were problems with braces and code put in a wrong place. Also, instead of:

```
ItemsData dataitem = new ItemsData
            {
            value0 = splitLines[0];
            value1 = splitLines[1];
            value2 = splitLines[2];
            value3 = splitLines[3];
            value4 = splitLines[4];
        }
        items.Add(dataitem);
```

I used:

```
ItemsData dataitem = new ItemsData
            {
                value0 = splitLines[0],
                value1 = splitLines[1],
                value2 = splitLines[2],
                value3 = splitLines[3],
                value4 = splitLines[4],
            };
            items.Add(dataitem);
```

And that solved the problem.

Here is clean working code:

```
public async void ReadFile()
    {

        var path = @"CPU.xls";
        var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

        var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
        var readFile = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);

        foreach (string line in readFile.OrderBy(line =>
        {
            int lineNo;
            var success = int.TryParse(line.Split(';')[4], out lineNo);
            if (success) return lineNo;
            return int.MaxValue;
        }))
        {
            string[] splitLines = line.Split(';');

            ObservableCollection<ItemsData> items = new ObservableCollection<ItemsData>();
            for (int index = 0; index < splitLines.Length; index++)
            {
                ItemsData dataitem = new ItemsData
                {
                    value0 = splitLines[0],
                    value1 = splitLines[1],
                    value2 = splitLines[2],
                    value3 = splitLines[3],
                    value4 = splitLines[4],
                };
                items.Add(dataitem);
            }
            itemsControl.DataContext = items;
        }

    }
```

I yet need to fix the layout as for now all the textblocks show up in same column and they overlap.

Thank you Alexej for your help!

**Edit 3----**
To put textblocks on separate columns in xaml I did like so:

```
 <ScrollViewer>
                <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      FontSize="24">

                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="Auto"
                          Margin="0 12"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Name="txtblk0" Text="{Binding value0}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Name="txtblk1" Text="{Binding value1}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="2"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Name="txtblk2" Text="{Binding value2}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="3"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Name="txtblk3" Text="{Binding value3}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="4"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Name="txtblk4" Text="{Binding value4}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

This way each word from line is put on separate column. TextBlocks don't overlap anymore.

Unfortunately I didn't manage do showcase all file(all lines). For now each row in xaml is populated with same line from the file instead of pulling each line into separate rows in xaml.

What should I do in order to list all lines instead of just one line? 
I believe that there is problem on C# code side.

Answer (score 2):

First create class for data:

```
    public class itemsdata
{
  public string txt0 { get; set; }
  public string txt1 { get; set; }
  public string txt2 { get; set; }
  public string txt3 { get; set; }
  public string txt4 { get; set; }
}
```

after it, create collection

```
 ObservableCollection<itemsdata> items = new ObservableCollection<itemsdata>();
```

and fill it:

```
for (int index = 0; index < splitLines.Length; index++)
        {
           itemsdata dataitem=new itemsdata
           {
               txt0=splitLines[0];
               txt1=splitLines[1];
               txt2=splitLines[2];
               txt2=splitLines[3];
               txt2=splitLines[4];
           }
            items.Add(dataitem);
        }
itemsControl.DataContext = items;
```

change binging to

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

and add new fields to datatemplate

```
<TextBlock Name="txtblk0" Text="{Binding txt0}" />
<TextBlock Name="txtblk1" Text="{Binding txt1}" />
<TextBlock Name="txtblk2" Text="{Binding txt2}" />
<TextBlock Name="txtblk3" Text="{Binding txt3}" />
<TextBlock Name="txtblk4" Text="{Binding txt4}" />
```

Comment: I get some errors with your code, can you check my edit please/

Comment: I guess I am putting Your code in wrong place as I get errors other classes too.

Comment: } expected - that's very usual error. Put class inside namespace (not inside class). If you show whole your code I can help you

Comment: inside onloaded or button click event. where you want to bind data in your code

Comment: For now I have put the code to read file into a ReadFile class.

Comment: But when I put  your for statement inside of it i get the errors shown in my edit

Comment: }))
            { - find this place in code. that's something very strange there. you should remove some braces

Comment: This part of code is ugly, indeed, but it works and does not give errors.

Comment: It's a foreach statement with sorting funct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114454/discussion-between-alexej-sommer-and-paddy).